# observable data not available in subscribe

Tags: angular, angular2-services

Following is my api call, I have interceptor in between, so I am getting this data from localstorage. The data is stringified and saved. When I return it I convert into observable by observable.of(cachedata).

```
  getApplications(userid: string): Observable<any> {
    let data =this.httpclient.get(this._getAPIUrl('user/' + userid + '/applications'))
      .map((res: Response) => res.json())
      return data;
  }
```

I called it from component

```
  ngOnInit() {
        const userid = this.platformService.currentUserId;
        console.log(this.platformService.getApplications(userid));
}
```

it print result

```
Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: MapOperator}
```

if I subscribe this call data didn't get available.

```
 this.platformService.getApplications(userid)
  .subscribe(applications => {
            console.log('app ' + applications);
            const menuItems: MenuItem[] = [];
            menuItems.push(
                new MenuHeaderItem({
                    type: MenuItemType.Header,
                    title: 'Applications',
                    description: null
                }));
            Object.keys(applications).map(element => {
                menuItems.push(this.formatconversion(applications[element]));
            });
            this.menu = menuItems;
        });
```

console.log('app ' + applications) not coming.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code seems valid in a sense that the code in the subscribe block should be called once the http get call is successfully resolved. Do you get any errors in the console?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have problem with your code 
instead of this

```
getApplications(userid: string): Observable<any> {
let data =this.httpclient.get(this._getAPIUrl('user/' + userid + '/applications'))
  .map((res: Response) => res.json())
  return data;
```

}

use this

```
getApplications(userid: string): Observable<any> {
this.httpclient.get(this._getAPIUrl('user/' + userid + '/applications'))
  .map((res: Response) => res.json())
```

}

There is no need of of returning.

```
res.json()
```

will return what ever the server response is.try this and let me know if its work :)

Comment: Its not working, error Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'void' coming

Comment: getApplications(userid: string) {
this.httpclient.get(this._getAPIUrl('user/' + userid + '/applications'))
  .map((res: Response) => res.json())}                                                                        try this.for me its work.

Comment: In my case I am getting this object from local storage and I was saving httpresponse object and retrieving it back which was saved in string. So Here problem was httpresponse object cannot be save in string format and If I do, It can't parseback to normal object. I was getting invalid json for converting to js object. This was the problem.

Comment: yes , we can't store httpresponse object in a string, that is why we use res.json() in server to send that to the component and there we can see the type of object comming from the server and accordingly can store that object.